# What is a good gift for hospitality in Nepal

Tags: local-customs, nepal, gifts

I am planning an extended Motorbike tour through Nepal and India and was wondering what a good token of appreciation would be .. besides money .. to give to people inviting me for a meal or giving me accommodation for a night?

I didn't bring any small souvenirs from Australia which is a shame.

Comment: Ferrari? iPhone? Sorry but your question is option based and not really answerable.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic here, the "small gift cerimony" he is talking about is somewhat specific to a country.

Comment: Normally this would be considered an "opinion-based" question, but considering it's really more about what type of gift is appropriate given the specific social custom, rather than a shopping recommendation, I think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

I just asked my host here in Kathmandu and without hesitation he replied... CHOCOLATE! Not the local stuff but nice imported chocolate. Apparently it's a big hit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can gift them imported perfumes/deos (if you have any) or Socks (for a nice long memory),

Comment: what lets you think so? specifically for Nepal?